# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Typescript Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently using Next.js and TypeScript and I'm confused on the error message I'm getting here.
Here's some context to the situation. I'm making an API call and I'm receiving an Object of arrays.

```
const fetchDogBreeds = async () => {
      const res: any = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
      const data: any = res.data.message;
      setDogBreeds(
        Object.entries(data).map(
          (breed:any) => breed[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + breed[0].substring(1)
        )
      );
    };
```

The code runs fine but I'm getting this TypeScript Error and I don't understand what it means.
Error:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

I'm a little new to TypeScript so I'm a little confused how to get this error to go away. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the line which gives an error? I guess that it is generated on `setDogBreeds`; if it's correct, then how it is defined?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to define the type of `res` array like this

```
const res: string[] = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
```

Without assigning the type of array it will be default set as `never`

Comment: I then get
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
Is that because its returning an object of arrays instead of an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Add the response type to `axios.get`, this will be passed on as the type of `response.data`.

```js
export interface DogBreeds {
  message: Record<string, string[]>;
}

const fetchDogBreeds = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get<DogBreeds>("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");

  const data = res.data.message;

  // call setDogBreeds and do other stuff. 
}
```

Also you need to supply the correct parameters to map:

```js
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]: string[]) => {});
```

Comment: That gives me this: 
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: I think you need to provide a type argument to `SetStateArg<string[]>` when creating `setDogBreeds`. I've not used react hooks, so I'm not sure about the types there.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to this:

```
const fetchDogBreeds = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
      const data = res.data.message;
      const listOfDogBreeds: any = Object.entries(data).map(
        (breed: any) => breed[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + breed[0].substring(1)
      );
      setDogBreeds(listOfDogBreeds);
    };
```

and I'm not getting anymore TypeScript errors